# Dynamic :After Pseudo-Element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

My brain isn't quite wrapping around this one: I'm working with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements on my `h1`. My `h1` has a `100% width`.

I want the `:after` to be a repeated background graphic that fills the open gap, post-text, but can't figure out how to make this work dynamically (ie: Whether the title is "Home" or "All About Awesome Products", the `:after` will repeat until it hits the end of the 100%).

Example:

```
.main h1:before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(images/before-services.jpg);
    width:18px;
    height:14px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.main h1 {
    color:#373737;
    text-shadow:0px 2px #5ac166;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Mister Giacco Bold';
    font-size:2em;
    width:100%;
}
.main h1:after {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(images/after-services.jpg) repeat-x;
    width:80%;
    height:15px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: "*that fills the open gap*": which open gap?

Comment: An image with your desired output would help greatly, or I suspect you'll get several misguided answers.

Comment: looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/53nfU/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work but it requires an additional `<span>`

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/HEzDJ)

**HTML**

```
<h1><span>A Fancy Title</span></h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

h1 span {
    display: inline-blspaock;
  position: relative;  
}

h1 span:before,
h1 span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 span:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
h1 span:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could virtually reduce width to zero of `:after` with a negative right `margin`, or set it in `absolute` `position`, either choice , `overflow:hidden` on `h1` will be useful.

```
h1:before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  width:18px;
  height:14px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
h1 {
  color:#373737;
  text-shadow:0px 2px #5ac166;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family: 'Mister Giacco Bold';
  font-size:2em;
  overflow:hidden;
}
h1:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:15px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:-100%;/* reduce virtually size to 0 or use position:absolute + margin-top:~ 0.4em */
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzGuh